# Combining Context Values (filter and queryset) - Python - Django Views - Filter and User

Tags: python, django, variables, filter, user-permissions

I need to combine two context values in my views.py for my python Django website. One is a filter at the top of the screen that filter all displayed data below and it looks like this...

```
context['filter'] = Sheet_Building_Filter(request.GET, queryset=Sheet_Building.objects.all())
```

The other is not a page filter but it filters and returns all the data that is from the user that is currently logged in and it looks like...

```
context['user'] = Sheet_Building.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

I need to combine these to loop through both of them in HTML at the same time. I thought something like this would work but it didn't...

```
    context['user_and_filter'] = Sheet_Building_Filter(request.GET, queryset=Sheet_Building.objects.filter(user=request.user))
```

This just displays the data and doesn't show the filter itself. I'm not sure if the filter works but isn't displaying the fields to filter by or if it is just not working at all. Im not sure why and I can't find any information of a filter and user data is combined into one value. I need it combined because I can't do a nested for-loop in HTML. Code below. Thanks!

views.py

```
def listdata_building(request):
    sheet = Sheet_Building.objects.all()
    context = {"sheet": sheet}

    context['user_and_filter'] = Sheet_Building_Filter(request.GET, queryset=Sheet_Building.objects.filter(user=request.user))
    context['user'] = Sheet_Building.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    return render(request, 'sheets/individual/list_data_building.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Sheet_Building(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True, related_name="Building", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspection Date')
    time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspection Time')
    inspection_type = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=INSPECTION_TYPE_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspection Type')
    flname = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspector')
    report_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Report Date')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=29, choices=DEPARTMENT_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Department')
    responsible_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Responsible Person')
    building_address = models.CharField(max_length=52, choices=BUILDING_ADDRESS, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Building and Address')
    floor = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=FLOOR_LEVEL_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Floor / Level')
    room = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Area / Room')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LOCATION_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Location')
    priority = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Priority')
    hazard_level = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=HAZARD_LEVEL_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Hazard Level')
    concern = models.CharField(max_length=31, choices=CONCERN_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Concern')
    codes = models.CharField(max_length=51, choices=CODES_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Element and Code')
    correction = models.TextField(max_length=160, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Corrective Action')
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Image', upload_to='gallery')
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Inspector's note")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pk']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.flname or 'None'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('list_building')
```

filter.py

```
class Sheet_Building_Filter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Sheet_Building
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['image', 'time', 'location', 'correction', 'notes', 'floor', 'room', 'priority', 'responsible_name', 'user']
```

HTML:

```
<div class="filterbar_BI">
    <form method="get">
        {{ user_and_filter.form }}
        <button style="background-color: #2f3d50; border-radius: 16px;" class="filterbutton_BI btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% if user_and_filter %}
    {% for post in user_and_filter %}
        {{ post.date }}
        {{ post.time }}
        {{ post.inspection_type }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In your views `sheet = Sheet_Building.objects.all()` contains every data from that field whether it is from logged in user or not. Then why are you trying to filter it again. Are you trying to get the data which is not owned by the logged in user.

Comment: @Rasheed kotoor its somewhat irrelevent

Comment: @Rasheed kotoor turns out the solution I said I got to didn't actually and didn't have the user aspect added so Im back to square 1, Any Help?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get what you have said.

Answer (score 0):

In your views `sheet = Sheet_Building.objects.all()` contains every data from that field whether it is from logged in user or not. Then why are you trying to filter it again. Are you trying to get the data which is not owned by the logged in user.

Comment: I replaced it with context = {}. it does the same thing. I never looped through the sheets variable I just used it to define context.